# Using different databases based on user request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've installed Laravel-4 and jenssegers / Laravel-MongoDB which has the same interface to Eloquent model as Laravel, so everything is pretty transparent and 1 database connection works OK.

what I'm trying to do, is switch to another database based on user request (Consider it as API that decided where to go and grab data).

This is what I did:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
$dbPrefix = $request->segment(1);

if (!is_null($dbPrefix)) {
    $dbName = strtolower($dbPrefix);
    $newDb = DB::connection('mongodb_'.$dbName);
}
});
```

From here.. I don't know what to do.. Is it connected to new database that way? how do I tell my Laravel to use $newDb when I refer to DB constant in Models?

But I want it to happen before application starts, so specifying "$connection" variable in model or using explicit call to other database like DB::connection('mongodb2')->query(...) is no good for me.

Thanks

Comment: Read [This Article](http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections)

Comment: That's exactly what I didn't wanted to do... thus I asked the question, I saw this article recently.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this would be:

/app/filters.php:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
$dbPrefix = $request->segment(1);

if (!is_null($dbPrefix)) {
    $connectionName = 'mongodb_'.strtolower($dbPrefix);
    Config::set('database.default', $connectionName);
}
});
```

/config/database.php:

```
'mongodb_soccer' => array(
        'driver'   => 'mongodb',
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'port'     => 27017,
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'SoccerData'
    ),

    'mongodb_tennis' => array(
        'driver'   => 'mongodb',
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'port'     => 27017,
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'TennisData'
    )
```

Requests:

> site.com/soccer
>   will get connection mongodb_soccer
>
> site.com/tennis 
>   will get connection mongodb_tennis

You can pre-authorize it in default "admin" database where your users are stored, and then switch to any database connection per user request to get the actual data.

I needed it this way for API development.

Good luck

Comment: You may also consider moving the logic (in the `before` filter) to a Service Provider class, perhaps one used in place of the default database service provider. (Extend the default one, change as needed, and replace your new one with the one provided on install). Either way can work fine. The above is probably simpler, assuming it works for you!

Comment: That's a great input anyway, I will check it tomorrow when I get to the code. One of the reasons asking it is to know few opinions about how this can be achieved. If there's an option to move out the logic from filter - I'd be happy to do that. Thank you.